# Invoice generation wkhtmltopdf font missing

Tags: drupal, pdf, invoice

I have a problem generating invoices on CiviCRM-4.6.16 with wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1 on Drupal (7.43).

In the template I define a font-family

```
@font-face {
font-family:LiberationSans-Regular;
src:
url(/ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/fonts/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf);}
```

In the Body I define a table I want to use the font like this:

```
      <table style = "padding-right:19px;font-family:LiberationSans-Regular;" width = "500" height = "100" border = "0" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "1">
```

The font is always ignored, except when I use a system/default font (e.g. Courier).

I tried numerous locations on where to put the fonts, since I suspected a permission problem or something like that, but apparently nothing helps and I can't get other fonts in the pdf export.

I verified that wkhtmltopdf is used (via meta data of the pdf).

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you inspect your webserver logs, do you see `wkhtmltopdf` make requests for font files at the locations you expect while requesting and rendering the invoice HTML? Filesystem permissions shouldn't be an issue since `wkhtmltopdf` would be requesting the files over the network, just like any other browser. So may be worthwhile confirming that this behaviour matches what you see for "normal" desktop browsers.

Comment: [This related SE question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14864224/43034) suggests that `wkhtmltopdf` 0.11.x has/had issues resolving relative URLs in fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Another option to try is to use inline fonts encoded in the base64 format. This prevents file system permission problems. More information can be found in [this blog entry](https://blog.shaharia.com/use-google-web-fonts-for-wkhtmltopdf-tools-to-convert-html-to-pdf/).